# How to inject the Doctrine ObjectManager into form element

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm working on my custom User module, which basically uses ZfcUser as the foundation. Since every application is different and requires different meta information about users I want this to be easily configurable using a config array.

In my module's global config file I define the custom form fields and in the Module's onBootstrap I extend the ZfcUser registration form using the init event of ZfcUser\Form\Register. So in short I want to do something like this:

```
$sharedEvents->attach('ZfcUser\Form\Register',
                'init',
                function($e) use ($sm)
                {
                    /* @var $form \ZfcUser\Form\Register */
                    $form = $e->getTarget();

                    // Get relevant config
                    $config = $sm->get('config');
                    if ( array_key_exists('redev_user', $config) && is_array($config['redev_user']) )
                    {
                        if ( array_key_exists('custom_fields', $config['redev_user']) && is_array($config['redev_user']['custom_fields']) )
                        {
                            foreach ($config['redev_user']['custom_fields'] as $curCustomField)
                            {
                                $form->add($curCustomField);
                            }
                        }
                    }
[...]
```

In my config file I then define the custom form fields like this:

```
<?php
return array(
    'redev_user' => array(
        'custom_fields' => array(
            // Custom fields which will be added to the registration form
            array(
                    'name' => 'firstname',
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'options' => array(
                            'label' => 'First name',
                    ),
            ),
```

I do the same thing for the validators; they are being defined in the config file and attached to the form elements in the onBootstrap.

This all works nice and dandy, except when I need a Doctrine form element. In my specific case I would like to use a DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect for the country selectbox. In my config this would look like this:

```
array(
           'name' => 'country',
           'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
           'options' => array(
           'label' => 'Country',
           //'object_manager' => $sm->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager'),
           'target_class'   => 'RedevUser\Entity\Country',
           'property'       => 'countryname',
           'is_method'      => false,
           'find_method'    => array(
               'name'   => 'findBy',
               'params' => array(
                               'criteria' => array(),
                                'orderBy'  => array('countryname' => 'ASC'),
                           ),
            ),
       ),
     ),
```

Note the commented out line for the object_manager. The ObjectSelect element obviously needs the ObjectManager. The question is how do I inject the ObjectManager while rendering the form based on the config.

I was thinking to render the form element myself and then check if it's an instance of some interface or base class of DoctrineModule\Form\Element. However it turns out there is no such base class or interface. The only thing those elements have in common is that they have a getProxy. Right now my code in onBootstrap looks like this:

```
foreach ($config['redev_user']['custom_fields'] as $curCustomField)
{
    $formElemFactory = $form->getFormFactory();
    $elem = $formElemFactory->createElement($curCustomField);

    if ($elem instanceof \DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect)
    {
         // Inject ObjectManager
         $elem->getProxy()->setObjectmanager($sm->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager'));
    }

    $form->add($elem);
}
```

But I don't really want to check for the different Doctrine form element types. Also it seems a bit dirty to do it like this. Any opinions or ideas of how to do this better/cleaner?

Comment: Well, that however is pretty much how you have to do this. There is no way to set the EM from the config file. When using form factory you'll have to set the EM after the elements have been added to the form. Either by looping through all elements or by knowing what elements need the EM

Comment: Okay thanks for the input. I guess I'll stick to this idea for now then. I will just change the instanceof check to a type check to catch all Doctrine form elements in one go. Not very elegant, but it works.